# Push Notification APNS Certificate USAGE:

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I need to create an iPhone app, that uses a push notification feature. I have created the "aps_developer.identity.cer" certificate and downloaded it from Apple Developer account. Is this certificate has any importance at the iPhone App side OR it is solely used at SERVER side to send Device TOKEN? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: see this url:   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Comment: also see this Url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357139/how-to-get-message-from-push-notification-message-before-notification-received-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both. You need separate certificates for development and release that support push notifications as well as a distribution certificate (Ad hoc or AppStore) that is linked to the AppID in the other certificates these are used to sign the app as well as being used for the server.

E.g. If you are debugging, the server needs to use the development certificate, if you are testing or have released the application, the server needs to use the distribution certificate. The apple push servers change depending on which method you are using. I would read the apple documentation on push notifications which also covers the provisioning side of things.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

As far as creating the server certificate, I used this guide and found it very helpful:
http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/CertificateCreation

Good Luck!